# If a credit card won't read when swiped, does wrapping it in plastic actually help and if so, why?

Tags: electromagnetism

I've on occasion seen when a cashier has trouble getting a credit card to read, will wrap it in a thin plastic grocery bag, and try swiping it again. Much to my surprise, it seemed to work.

Since the card uses a magnetic strip, I can't see how the plastic would help. Is there any reason it should, or is this a case where it worked, but not because of the plastic?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [best explanation I have seen for this](http://cr4.globalspec.com/thread/2432/plastic-bags-improve-credit-card-swiping) is that the plastic bag increases the distance between the read head and the magnetic strip.  As the magnetic strip is used, small particles break off and become embedded elsewhere on the stripe.  These have very little magnetic force, but enough that they throw off today's more sensitive readers, even though they're embedded in a larger area of stronger magnetism.

By increasing the distance between the read head and the mag stripe, even though it's just the thickness of the plastic bag, the smaller "noisy" bits impart a smaller field on the sensor than the larger areas of magnetic material surrounding them. It increases the signal to noise ratio by placing a low pass filter between the strip and the read head.

In other words, it's similar to putting on earmuffs so you can only hear the bass line of a piece of music, muffling the midrange, and almost muting the high range frequencies.

Comment: I was ready to verdict this question as a myth. Your answer is convincing. +1

Comment: I've seen it at least appear to work. Good explanation for why.

Comment: So why aren't cards laminated?

Comment: How does one experimentally confirm this model/explanation beyond the existence of the plastic bag trick? Can the breakdown be characterized? The Answer is partly a myth without more. A comment at CR4 cited other experimental data that's a little awkward -- a card was read OK by all readers except one, where a plastic bag worked. No-one addressed that case there. One of the constraints for card design and manufacture must be variabilities in the sensitivity and the signal processing sophistication of readers. Otherwise, I guess we'd all tape up our cards or they'd be manufactured differently.

Comment: @Tom They are, but the lamination thickness is measured on the order of thousands of an inch, and even if it were thicker it would eventually wear out.

Comment: @Tom One of my points succinctly put. Good. I've partly suggested what I guess may be the answer, that there will be some rather awkward historical constraints on the magnetic stripe's specification.

Comment: @Peter One would use a high resolution magnetic scanning system - similar to what is used in the hard drive industry - to map out the field on the card in the micro scale.  Do so at different distances from the card to get a full 3D map, and you should be able to show whether this trick works due to the process described or due to some other process.

Comment: @Peter Alternately, one would use an oscilloscope to quantify the signal directly off the read head in the failing scanner vs the signal on a good scanner with a variety of cards, failing, not failing, covered, uncovered.  We should be able to gather a lot of good data regarding what kind of signal the bad cards present to the two different readers, what the bag changes about that signal, and discern what the mechanism is that causes this to work.  I strongly suspect that the "better" readers have a better signal processing chain that performs the same function as the bag.

Comment: On the off chance that someone is able to provide units for me to test, I'll perform the oscilloscope tests.

Comment: @Adam I suppose so. Card manufacturers must have process engineers, perhaps even physicists, but I wonder whether part of the specification for cards is "will wear out after two to three years of normal use for the sake of our bottom line". On the other side, the credit card company wants this cost center under some sort of control, and doesn't want customers to hate their cards failing too often. Your response to Tom pushed me over the fence anyhow. I'd been holding out on the +1, like a dork, but your Answer is obviously a useful starting point. Send Adam your credit cards!

Comment: @Peter There is, unfortunately, no "normal use". I've never had to use this trick, but I use my credit card only a few times a month. Those who use their cards multiple times daily will of course have a higher failure rate. There is likely to be someone in the industry who has characterized the failure rate against the cost of a more durable lamination, and minimized the total cost. *Regardless*, the cards do eventually fail.  At that point we can only study what the failure mechanism is, and what it means for the various tricks people use to increase the life of their card.

Comment: ""They are, but the lamination thickness is measured on the order of thousands of an inch,"" I just checked one of my cards, there is a very thin clear laquer, if any. This magnetic strip looks very much as the magnetic coating on tape recorders or on floppy disks. My experience with tapes and floppys is, that the problem can be the coating rubbed off and covering the magnetic head as well. (The magnetic coating on tapes etc is in fact a laquer) RE "Why", who pays/has to pay for replacement? And on top: this is an dying technology, nobody wants to invest in improvements.